# User-friendly URLs in Yii

Tags: .htaccess, yii

I've been doing some experiments with Yii, to see if it will suit my needs. The first thing I wanted to enable was the user-friendly URLs.

What I want to achieve: to go from this URL `webapproot/index.php?r=site/contact` to this URL `webapproot/contact`.

What I've done:

- Created an aplication using Yiic (`php YiiRoot/framework/yiic.php webapp testdrive`)
- Followed the steps 2 and 6 of [this link from Yii's documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url) ("User-friendly URLs" and "Hiding index.php").

What happens is that I keep getting a 404. Any ideas of what I did wrong?

Below are some relevant excerpts to this question:

### [project root]/protected/config/main.php

```
(...)
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
(...)
```

### [project root]/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

### /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
(...)
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
(...)
<Directory [path to my web projects folder]>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
</Directory>
(...)
```

Comment: pentium's answer should solve it, unless you have a system where your webserver document root and the webapp's root are in different folders, which could lead to another problem

Comment: Hm, got it. Yeah, the /site/ problem would be solved with that, but I'd kindly ask for you to take a look at .htaccess thing too, 'cause I'm not able to access my pages now with just `webapproot/index.php/site/contact` (Which is the link that the CMenu generates), I need to manually add "index.php" to the URL, like this: `webapproot/index.php/site/contact`

Comment: your comment has me confused, do you want to remove index.php or not? with your current .htaccess (and showScriptName false) the app doesn't need index.php in the url.

Comment: Yes, I want to remove index.php. I thought that I wouldn't need it but, when I try to access the URL `webapproot/site/login`, I get a "404 Not Found - The requested URL webapproot/site/login was not found on this server."

Comment: ok, this is a problem with your htaccess, check my answer in a bit

Comment: any solution to this? same problem! using dreamhost as a host. they say mod_rewrite is on for every account type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your latest comment it looks like that you need to set [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) as well. As i mentioned in my first comment to your question, if you have your webserver's DocumentRoot and your webapp in separate folders, then this problem could arise. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /~username/yourwebappfolder
#rest of your rewrite conditions/rules
```

To debug htaccess or other server configurations, check your server error_log, for mac lion it is in the file: */var/log/apache2/error_log*

Comment: Worked like a charm. As it was my main problem, I'll give the solution answer to you, although Kor's and Pentium10's answers were very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Your link must be `webapproot/site/contact` as in controller/action if you want just /contact you need to create a contact controller with index view.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. That's a likely solution, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to move that outside `SiteController` (though @Pentium10's answer is good enough), you can add a rule per page you want to extract from the `/site/` path. However, this is a little dirty, because you need to try not to collide with other Controllers named equal to contact, login or whatever:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        'contact'=>'site/contact',
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```

You are basically telling Yii that any request to `/contact` is actually a request to `/site/contact`. If you are at the beginning of the project creation and you are still with the basic default layouts, look at the `CMenu`'s Contact link, you will see that now it points to `webapproot/contact` instead of `webapproot/site/contact`

Have a nice day

Comment: A great solution too. More helpful in a practical view, but it has its problems. Thank you.